# Move nodes with a VBox or HBox

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

Feels like i've tried every method with the description that indicates it does what I want.

But I'm wondering, is there any way to set the coordinates or position of nodes within a VBox.

```
public VBox boxButtons(){
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 100, 10, 10));
    vbox.setSpacing(12);
    btnBrowse.setPrefWidth(150);
    btnBrowse.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
    btnGetRange.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
    btnGetRange.setPrefWidth(150);
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(btnBrowse, btnGetRange);
    return vbox;
}
```

I've tried setLayoutX and Y as well. I can't seem to be able to move nodes within my HBox and VBoxes at all. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what you are looking to do, and how the results are different from what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually see where you are doing anything that you say in your post about setLayoutX or setLayoutY.

There has already been a similar question answered. It's not exactly the same but it should help you.

[How to move items with in VBox(Change order by Dragging) in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929161/how-to-move-items-with-in-vboxchange-order-by-dragging-in-javafx)

I would suggest this is marked as duplicate.

Comment: Maybe I was a bit unclear. I want to decide the layout of where my nodes end up being placed inside a VBox or HBox. Even though the classes include methods that suggest this is possible, I haven't found a way that works.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear from your question exactly what you're trying to do, but maybe this will help:

`HBox` and `VBox` (and other layout panes) manage the layout of the manages nodes for you. Either use a plain `Pane`, or call `setManaged(false)` on the nodes you want to manually position.